# How do we hash/encrypt multiple columns value into aws dynamodb?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently working on a payment api that will stored the values into aws dynamodb.
Currently, i have managed to link it together with aws but now i'm just wondering if there is any method such that i am able to encrypt multiple columns value (like payeeName and payeeCardNo) before storing into the aws dynamodb??

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.payment.model;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "CitiBank")
public class CitiBank {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey 
    private String paymentID;
    
    // payment Information
    @DynamoDBAttribute 
    private String payeeName;


    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String payeeCardNo;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private int price;

    
    public String getPaymentID(){
        return paymentID;
    }

    public void setPaymentID(String paymentID){
        this.paymentID = paymentID;
    }

    public String getPayeeName(){
        return payeeName;
    }

    public void setPayeeName(String payeeName){
        this.payeeName = payeeName;
    }

    public String getPayeeCardNo(){
        return payeeCardNo;
    }

    public void setPayeeCardNo(String payeeCardNo){
        this.payeeCardNo = payeeCardNo;
    }

    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price){
        this.price = price;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to encrypt and why? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-dynamodb.html

Comment: I want to encrypt the payeeCardNo and payeeName for security issue

Comment: "for security issue" is not a proper reasoning. DynamoDB data is already encrypted at rest - what attack vector are you concerned about, how would explicitly encrypting some data remedy that?

Comment: I am currently basing on my project requirement, whereby it say Any PII information (member name) should be encrypted. Hence, i am just wondering if there is any method for me to encrypt the information in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the KMS service Java API to encrypt data and then store the encrypted data in DynamoDB. Here is a Java V2 example that shows you how to encrpt/decrypt data.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/kms/src/main/java/com/example/kms/EncryptDataKey.java

Also - not sure that you are aware that a newer API exists for Java and AWS. You are using an older version that the AWS SDK team recommends moving away from. They recommend using the DynamoDB V2 API.

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

Just tested this use case and it worked. I encrypted the data using a KMS key prior to writing it to the table.

[image]

Java V2 code that encrypts the **albumTitleValue** data and then adds it to the DynamoDB table:

```
public static void putItemInTable(DynamoDbClient ddb,
                                      KmsClient kmsClient,
                                      String tableName,
                                      String key,
                                      String keyVal,
                                      String albumTitle,
                                      String albumTitleValue,
                                      String awards,
                                      String awardVal,
                                      String songTitle,
                                      String songTitleVal,
                                      String keyId ){

        HashMap<String,AttributeValue> itemValues = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();

        //Encrypt the albumTitleValue before writing it to the table
        SdkBytes myBytes = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(albumTitleValue);

        EncryptRequest encryptRequest = EncryptRequest.builder()
                .keyId(keyId)
                .plaintext(myBytes)
                .build();

        EncryptResponse response = kmsClient.encrypt(encryptRequest);

        // Get the encrypted data
        SdkBytes encryptedData = response.ciphertextBlob();

        // Add content to the table
        itemValues.put(key, AttributeValue.builder().s(keyVal).build());
        itemValues.put(songTitle, AttributeValue.builder().s(songTitleVal).build());
        itemValues.put(albumTitle, AttributeValue.builder().bs(encryptedData).build());
        itemValues.put(awards, AttributeValue.builder().s(awardVal).build());

        PutItemRequest request = PutItemRequest.builder()
                .tableName(tableName)
                .item(itemValues)
                .build();

        try {
            ddb.putItem(request);
            System.out.println(tableName +" was successfully updated");

        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.format("Error: The Amazon DynamoDB table \"%s\" can't be found.\n", tableName);
            System.err.println("Be sure that it exists and that you've typed its name correctly!");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
    }
```

You can find additional DynamoDB Java V2 examples here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb